# MS Access 2010 query returns more rows than in table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a query in MS Access 2010 which returns more rows than there are in the source table.

I have tried to recreate what is happening with a simplified example, but could not get the same effect. I have set the parameters so that all records in the source table should be included, but only those that match from the other tables.

The `tbl_Toyota2012` has 178'205 records... the result of the query returns 180'365 records.

Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
   tbl_Toyota2012.[FC-Teile-Nr], tbl_Toyota2012.BEZEICHNUNG, tbl_Toyota2012.PFC, 
   tbl_Toyota2012.PC, tbl_Toyota2012.WARENGRUPPE, tbl_PriceCodes.PRICE_CODE, 
   tbl_PriceCodes.NORMAL_FACTOR, tbl_Toyota2012.EK_NETTO_MANDANT AS EP, 
   tbl_Toyota2012.UPE, tbl_Toyota2012.RABATTSATZ, tbl_NWGW_Key.ZUTEILUNG, 
   tbl_Toyota2012.UMSATZ_2012_UNITS AS [Volumen 2012], 
   [tbl_Toyota2012]![UMSATZ_2012_UNITS]*[tbl_Toyota2012]![UPE]*(1-([tbl_Toyota2012]![RABATTSATZ]/100)) AS NettoUmsatz

FROM 
   (tbl_Toyota2012 
LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_NWGW_Key ON (tbl_Toyota2012.PC = tbl_NWGW_Key.ProdCode) AND (tbl_Toyota2012.PFC = tbl_NWGW_Key.PFC)) 
LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_PriceCodes ON (tbl_Toyota2012.MODELL_ID = tbl_PriceCodes.MODEL_ID) AND (tbl_Toyota2012.PC = tbl_PriceCodes.PROD_CODE) AND (tbl_Toyota2012.PFC = tbl_PriceCodes.PROD_FUNC_CODE);
```

Can anyone tell me why this might happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will happen if there is more than a 1:1 relationship between tbl_Toyota2012 and the two tables you are joining on (PriceCodes and tbl_NWGW_Key) as there will be more rows.

i.e. If for each entry in tbl_Toyota2012 there are several entries in PriceCodes or tbl_NWGW_Key.

To answer your comments:

If you have a table 'Parent' that joins to table 'Children' a parent with two children will return more than one line.

`SELECT Parent.Name, Child.Name FROM Parent
   INNER JOIN Child on Parent.ID = ChildID`

This might return:

`[Parent Name], [Child Name]`

`Bob, Susan`

`Bob, David`

Comment: Thanks for the answer... is there a way to filter the table so that I can see these duplicate rows?

Comment: Just to double check. You mean that I have a record in `tbl_Toyota2012` which has match in `PriceCodes` and another one in `tbl_NWGW_Key`, but they are not shown on one line?

Comment: @excelnova If you `SELECT parent.name, Count(Child.name) FROM Parent INNER JOIN Child on Parent.ID = ChildID  GROUP BY parent.name HAVING Count(Child.name)>1` you will get a list of records with duplicates.